# How to discover if a method (parameter) in a subclass has an annotation defined in the implemented interface?

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, methods, annotations

Unfortunately it seems that annotation inheritance is severely restricted by the fact that only class-level annotations from classes (and not interfaces) can be inherited.

Consider this code:

```
interface Foo {
    @A
    void bar(String str, @B int i);
}

class FooImpl implements Foo {
    void bar(String str, @B int i) { ... }
}
```

If I have an instance of `FooImpl` is it possible to discover if the method has been annotated with `A` (either in the class (easy) or in the implemented interface)?

What about the method parameter? Is it possible to dicover if and which parameter has been annotated with `B`?

It seems that this is not possible with AspectJ and I need to use Java Reflection.

How would a solid solution look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its possible use `getInterfaces()` on the class object and query the result.

parameter annotation

```
package mawi12345;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface B {
    int version() default 0;
}
```

method annotation

```
package mawi12345;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Inherited
public @interface Revision {
    int minor() default 0;
    int major() default 1;
}
```

interface with annotations

```
package mawi12345;
public interface Foo {
    @Revision(minor=1, major=3)
    public void setMark(@B(version=3) int mark);
}
```

class with annotations and the Foo interface

```
package mawi12345;
public class Test implements Foo {

    public void setMark(int mark) {

    }

    @Revision(minor=2, major=4)
    public boolean isPassed() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
package mawi12345;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class ReflectionTest {

    public static void printAnnotations(Class<?> clazz) {
        // array of methods
        Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
        System.out.println("found "+methods.length+" methods");
        for (int i=0; i<methods.length; i++) {
            // get the annotations of this method
            Annotation[] methodAnnotations = methods[i].getAnnotations();
            // if you only wont to check for one annotation use getAnnotation(Class<T>)

            for (Annotation methodAnnotation : methodAnnotations) {
                System.out.println(methodAnnotation);
            }
            // get the parameter annotations (2d array) 
            Annotation[][] parameterAnnotations = methods[i].getParameterAnnotations();
            // get an array of parameters
            Class<?>[] parameters = methods[i].getParameterTypes();
            for(int x=0; x<parameterAnnotations.length; x++) {
                Class<?> parameter = parameters[x];
                for(Annotation annotation : parameterAnnotations[x]){
                    // print the parameter name and his annotation
                    System.out.println(parameter.getName() + " " + annotation);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create Test object
        Test test = new Test();
        // get the class
        Class<?> clazz = test.getClass();
        System.out.println("Class Test");
        // print annotations
        printAnnotations(clazz);
        System.out.println();

        // get the interfaces of the class
        Class<?>[] interfaces = clazz.getInterfaces();

        System.out.println("found "+interfaces.length+" interfaces");
        // print annotations for each interface
        for (Class<?> type : interfaces) {
            System.out.println(type);
            printAnnotations(type);
        }

    }

}
```

Output

```
Class Test
found 2 methods
@mawi12345.Revision(minor=2, major=4)

found 1 interfaces
interface mawi12345.Foo
found 1 methods
@mawi12345.Revision(minor=1, major=3)
int @mawi12345.B(version=3)
```